# Adding "--" to a command within xinit?

Tags: ubuntu, ltsp

A standard xinit command looks like this:

```
xinit /usr/local/bin/app -- :1 vt2
```

However, I have a command that looks like this:

```
xinit /usr/bin/xfreerdp -a 16 -u '' -x m -z --disable-wallpaper --disable-full-window-drag --disable-menu-animations --disable-theming --plugin rdpsnd --plugin rdpdr --data disk:Devices:/media/root -- 10.0.0.197 -- :1 vt2
```

Notice how the command given to xinit uses "--" in-and-of-itself (before the IP)?  Well, xinit complains about it:

```
Fatal server error:
Unrecognized option: 10.0.0.197
```

**How do I get xinit to allow the use of a "--" within the command given to it?**

Please note that I thought about moving the sub-command to it's own bash script, but this is for an LTSP server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
xinit /bin/sh -c "exec /usr/bin/xfreerdp -a 16 -u '' -x m -z --disable-wallpaper --disable-full-window-drag --disable-menu-animations --disable-theming --plugin rdpsnd --plugin rdpdr --data disk:Devices:/media/root -- 10.0.0.197" -- :1 vt2
```

Comment: `xinit`'s first parameter (and the first parameter after `--`) must be full pathnames; otherwise the default `xinitrc`/`xserverrc` respectively will be used and all the parameters will be passed on as parameters to it.  I would also `exec /usr/bin/xfreerdp` ...` there.

Comment: geekosaur: thanks for the edit. I was also thinking about the exec, nice catch